# Sorting structures in C

Tags: c

My question is whether it's possible to sort structures in C using the same function but upon a given argument?

My code is given below:

```
struct Process
{
   int pid;
   int at;
   int bt;
   int completed;
};
void sort(struct Process proc[]){
    int i, j;
    struct Process temp;
    for (i = 0; i < no_processes-1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < no_processes-i-1; j++)
            if (proc[j].at > proc[j+1].at){
                temp=proc[j+1];
                proc[j+1]=proc[j];
                proc[j]=temp;
            }
}
```

What I meant is that, I need to use the same sort function to sort a given structure, depending upon a given argument which specifies whether the structure should be sorted according to `proc.pid` or `proc.at` or `proc.bt`.

Is it possible to accomplish the above task? or should I implement three sort functions?

Comment: You're not allowed to use `qsort()`? If you can, you just need to write some compare functions.

Comment: You can do what `qsort` in the standard library does and accept a function pointer (to a comparison function) as an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the argument you pass in you can make the appropriate comparison, then you can check the result of the comparison to see if you need to swap.

For example:

```
enum { SORT_AT, SORT_BT, SORT_PID };

void sort(struct Process proc[], int sort_by){
    int i, j;
    struct Process temp;
    for (i = 0; i < no_processes-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < no_processes-i-1; j++) {
            int cmp = 0;
            switch (sort_by) {
            case SORT_AT:
                cmp = (proc[j].at > proc[j+1].at); break;
            case SORT_BT:
                cmp = (proc[j].bt > proc[j+1].bt); break;
            case SORT_PID:
                cmp = (proc[j].pid > proc[j+1].pid); break;
            }
            if (cmp){
                temp=proc[j+1];
                proc[j+1]=proc[j];
                proc[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```